# joining 3 tables mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

**Customer**

```
╔═══════╦══════════╗
║ CUSID ║ CUS NAME ║
╠═══════╬══════════╣
║     1 ║ AA       ║
║     2 ║ BB       ║
║     3 ║ CC       ║
╚═══════╩══════════╝
```

**CusSeaFood**

```
╔════╦═══════╦══════════╗
║ ID ║ CUSID ║   NAME   ║
╠════╬═══════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║     1 ║ SeaFoodA ║
║  2 ║     1 ║ SeaFoodB ║
║  3 ║     2 ║ SeaFoodC ║
╚════╩═══════╩══════════╝
```

**CusPizza**

```
╔════╦═══════╦══════╗
║ ID ║ CUSID ║ NAME ║
╠════╬═══════╬══════╣
║  1 ║     1 ║ PAA  ║
║  2 ║     2 ║ PBB  ║
╚════╩═══════╩══════╝
```

**CusSnack**

```
╔════╦═══════╦══════╗
║ ID ║ CUSID ║ NAME ║
╠════╬═══════╬══════╣
║  1 ║     2 ║ SAA  ║
║  2 ║     3 ║ SBB  ║
╚════╩═══════╩══════╝
```

Want to count how many Seafood, pizza or snack are order by which customer example like below.

```
Cus ID, Cus Name, Number Of SeaFood, Sea Food info, Number Of Pizza, Pizza info, Number of Snack, Snack info.
```

The customer may not be order all 3 types of food.

Comment: You need to use LEFT OUTER JOIN. What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to separately calculate each count via subquery in order for you to get correct results. This will prevent you to calculate duplicate records.

```
SELECT  a.*,
        COALESCE(b.totalSeaFood, 0) totalSeaFood,
        COALESCE(c.totalPizza, 0) totalPizza,
        COALESCE(d.totalSnack, 0) totalSnack
FROM    Customer a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  cusID, COUNT(*) totalSeaFood
            FROM    CusSeaFood
            GROUP   BY cusID
        ) b ON a.cusID = b.CusID
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  cusID, COUNT(*) totalPizza
            FROM    CusPizza
            GROUP   BY cusID
        ) c ON a.cusID = c.CusID
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  cusID, COUNT(*) totalSnack
            FROM    CusSnack
            GROUP   BY cusID
        ) d ON a.cusID = d.CusID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9908a8/1)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Result

```
╔═══════╦══════════╦══════════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║ CUSID ║ CUS NAME ║ TOTALSEAFOOD ║ TOTALPIZZA ║ TOTALSNACK ║
╠═══════╬══════════╬══════════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║     1 ║ AA       ║            2 ║          1 ║          0 ║
║     2 ║ BB       ║            1 ║          1 ║          1 ║
║     3 ║ CC       ║            0 ║          0 ║          1 ║
╚═══════╩══════════╩══════════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

"Sea Food info", "Pizza info", etc. in your example doesn't make sense to me. If the customer ordered more than one seafood or pizza, how is it supposed to be represented here?

Usually you'd expect to see multiple rows, one per ordered thing. And to get this info, you wouldn't even need a join, just a `UNION`.

```
SELECT * FROM CusSeaFood WHERE CusID = ?
UNION SELECT * FROM CusPizza WHERE CusID = ?
UNION SELECT * FROM CusSnack WHERE CusID = ?
```